# Putting messages in Eclipse form headers on a line beneath the title

Tags: eclipse, layout

I'm having some trouble with error messages in Eclipse form headers.  At the moment, the layout has the title on the left, toolbar buttons on the right, and any messages we put on the header (using `Form.setMessage()`) appear on a line with the title, i.e.

```
TITLE TITLE Please enter a name for this file.     [buttons]
```

This has the issue that whenever the program is used on a smaller monitor, non-maximised, or with several other panes surrounding this one, the toolbar gets compressed and the message gets truncated ridiculously.  You might see, for instance:

```
TITLE TITLE Plea...ile. [buttons]
```

A way of mitigating this issue would be to have the error message on a line underneath the title (preferably not underneath the buttons as well since they're quite tall).  Is there some way of making this happen?  Using a newline character results in a really odd look, with the error message indented to align with the end of the title:

```
TITLE TITLE                                        [buttons]
            Please enter a name for this file.
```

Obviously, this doesn't address the issue at all, just makes it look even worse.  What we're after is:

```
TITLE TITLE                                        [buttons]
Please enter a name for this file.
```

Any ideas?